# routing to a named outlet from named outlet, angular 4

Tags: angular, router-outlet

app's routes are:

```
{path: 'profile', component: ProfilePageComponent, outlet: 'bodyOutlet'
, children: [
{path: 'profile-personal-information', component: ProfilePersonalInformationComponent, outlet: 'profileOutlet'},
{path: 'profile-license-details', component: ProfileLicenseDetailsComponent, outlet: 'profileOutlet'}
```

]
}

so, I am able to navigate to the profilePageComponent:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { bodyOutlet: ['profile'] } }]);
```

but to navigate to profileOutlet from ProfilePageComponent isn't working with the following code:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets:  { 'bodyOutlet': [ 'profileOutlet', 'profile-personal-information']}}]);
```

or

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {profileOutlet: ['profile-personal-information']}}]);
```

so, I needed help on navigating from one named router outlet to another named router outlet

Comment: why are you using the outlet property? Why not just navigate using the path?

Comment: There are other router outlets as well, for modals and a few components